# Godot RichTextLabel BBCODE Table and List support

Tags: godot, bbcode

I am learning Godot. I am attempting to use bbcode tables and lists inside the RichTextLabel type. It doesn't appear to work. Am I doing something wrong, or are tables not supported?

[image]

I have tried multiple variant ways to define lists, but none of them seem to work. the [list] and [table] types do not appear in the godot documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are supported, but there isn't a list tag. You can see the supported tags at [BBCode in RichTextLabel](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/bbcode_in_richtextlabel.html).

The tables are not like HTML tables. You need to specify the number of columns and then add cells. There is no "tr" or "td". For example:

```
[table=2][cell][img=16]res://icon.png[/img][/cell][cell]Hello World[/cell][/table]
```

Comment: Thanks @Theraot Admittedly I am not familiar with BBCode so I was googling how to do the table syntax.